# PostgreSQL: Reference whole-table

Tags: postgresql

I have a project where data is being updated by 14 different users that will run over the course of a few months, collection approximately 5.5 thousand rows.. To avoid giving write access to each other's db I have given each their own DB with r/w access. At the end of the collection period I plan to collect them all to a single DB where they all will have read access only, still as individual tables.

My question comes to the following problem. In addition to 14 user tables brought into the read only DB, a last table will be created that will geo-reference each of the other tables as data collected at a specific location for use in POSTGIS.

All of the tutorials and docs I've looked at talk about referencing specific column values in another table, but never the whole table. Roughly the GPS geo-referencing table would look something like this:

```
COORDINATES    TABLE
x_lat,y_long   table_l
z_lat,w_long   table_m
a_lat,b_long   table_n
```

However from what I've been able to find online the REFERENCES column type is limited to something resembling the following:

```
COORDINATES    TABLE(col_z)
x_lat,y_long   col_z_value
```

Is the only solution to, when bring all the tables from different the individual DB's, to simply bring them into a single table where each row can be referenced by the individual device ID or user ID? I wanted to avoid having to do it that because 5500 rows x 14 tables will be rather large.

Based on the above context I am open to other solutions as well.

Thanks very much for any input!

Comment: I think I may have found what I'm looking for, the LEFT JOIN command, unless someone has a more appropriate solution: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-left-join/

Comment: That's my bad. I just didn't know what to put there. It's not supposed to be one data type, it's supposed to reference an entire, unique table. All rows, all columns. So there will be multiple data types in the referenced table. The referenced table represents the data collected data from a device at a given gps location. Table A, col_1 = gps coordinates(postgis plugin), col_2 = all data collected by that device.

Comment: Upon further inspection LEFT JOIN doesn't seem appropriate either. would the TABLE col be of type CHAR, being the name of the table, and then just write queries that interpret the reference independently?

Comment: Why not store the data in the same table with a single column prefix indicating its source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is no way to have a foreign key that points to different tables.

I think you should import the 14 tables into a single table, perhaps adding a column that indicated from which original table the data came (if you need that information).

Tables under 100000 rows are considered small these days, so I wouldn't worry on that account.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think this is the most appropriate solution for what I'm doing.